# Why isn't Parse storing the session, i.e. login isn't persistent

Tags: php, session, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse in PHP, but I can't get the login to be persistent.

Registration works, and login works as long as I don't leave the page. As soon as I refresh, it's gone.

The PHP session is active, and if I call `session_id` I see that the value isn't changing.

Here's how I'm initializing Parse and logging in:

```
Parse\ParseClient::initialize( 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx' );

session_start();

[...]

$user = ParseUser::logIn("$name","$pass");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After hours of cluelessness, I realised the mistake while writing this question. Posting anyway since it might be useful to other users.*

`session_start()` has to be called **before** `ParseClient::initialize`. That's it, it now works.

*With hindsight it looks obvious, of course.*